# How can I delete all files that match a list of patterns with Perl?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, file

I have a list of files and an array with some values that contains pattern of the filename

```
filename: awefsad-name1-x33

@array=("name1","name2","name3");
```

how to remove files that contain the name in array?

```
@files = ("*");
foreach $check(@files){
   foreach $i(@array){
      if($check =~ /\Q$i/){
          unlink $check;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Your variable names are very confusing and you are not using `strict` or `warnings`. Still it ought to work. Of course `*` is not a valid file name. Look at the `glob` built-in to get a list of files in a folder.

Comment: Did you just want to share some experiences instead of ask a question?

Comment: He is using a string `"*"` instead of a glob `glob "*"` or `<*>`.

Comment: I just want to grab all file names from a dir and remove those files that contains my pattern in тхе array, my code is not working, i need the right solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`glob` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to get your list of file names. You can also use [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html) to precompile the patterns into regular expressions. Using good names will make it easier to read your code, and `strict` and `warnings` will tell you about errors and mistakes you made.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say'; # just for demonstration
my @patterns = map { qr/\Q$_/ } ( "name1", "name2", "name3" );

FILE: foreach my $file ( glob '*' ) {
  foreach my $pattern (@patterns) {
    if ($file =~ $pattern) {
      say $file or warn qq{cannot delete $file: $!}; # replace with unlink
      next FILE;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Note that you can only delete each file once, so we are done with the list of patterns as soon as we've matched one and gotten rid of the file.

I changed the `unlink` to `say` so you can take a look at what it matches. For me it works:

```
my @patterns = map { qr/\Q$_/ } ( 'scratch', '.txt' );

__END__
data.txt
file2.txt
scratch.pl
scratch2.pl
```

Comment: Alternatively: `my $pattern = join '|' => map +quotemeta, @patterns; unlink for grep /$pattern/, <*>;`. Also, `unlink` returns success or failure, so it may be useful to add an `or die`/`or warn` clause.

Comment: too bad, it removes whole files, this code works only when i have 1 value in my array

`map { qr/\Q$_/ } ( "name1" );`

Comment: @Rocker I improved the answer, but I don't see what the problem is. Should have worked before. Works for me.

Comment: Oh I see, it's working! and what about if I want to remove files that are not matched with the regexp? just need two kind of scripts and I changed "if" condition to "unless" but it removes everything, even if pattern mathes, thought gonna work

Comment: In that case you will need to put everything into one match expression. Go with Zaid's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Joining the regular expressions into a single expression yields this single for loop to unlink the files.

```
my $match_re = join '|', map {"\Q$_"} ("name1","name2","name3");

for my $file (grep {/$match_re/} <*>) {
    print "unlink $file\n";
}
```